# Android - how to programatically set notification sound for future push notifications sent by FCM

Tags: android, audio, push-notification, android-preferences

My server is able to send FCM push notifications to my Android app users. The notifications are successfully delivered with default notification sound.
However, I want the app user to select sound from Ringtone Picker in the Preference screen.
I have been able to show Ringtone Picker in the Preference screen, but I don't know how to set the selected sound URI for future push notifications

So that when the future push notification of this app is received, the sound that user selected, should be played.

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Try using this? I assume in your app you are dealing with this class and library.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setSound(android.net.Uri)